Is there any way to know how long has an AWS AppStream ImageBuilder has been running for?
I am looking for a way to stop the AWS AppStream ImageBuilder.
I did some googling around but I don't seem to find a way to find how long has an ImageBuilder been running for, so that I then can write a script to stop the ImageBuilder, that have been running longer than a certain time period...
Output of this command aws appstream describe-image-builders --name  doesn't have any info related to LaunchTime
Anybody dealt with this before?
